# LINQ DataContext persistance best practice for many inserts

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, optimization

I have a logger class that is used all across my application, both in requests and threads. The logger consists of a database insert for each Log.Insert(string text). The logger is a static class, and a new database context is created for each call to Insert. There might be many calls to Insert, and a lot of database contexts simultaneously is not good for optimization. (I sometimes get database timeout, because of too many sql operations across the application - so optimization is indeed needed).

Can this be optimized by creating and storing a single database context in a static member of the Logger class, that is only used for the Log.Inserts? Or will this fail?

Simplified version of the logger class;

```
[Table]
public class Log
{
   [Column]
   public string Text { get; set; }

   private static DataContext DatabaseContextInsert { get; set; }

   public static void Insert(string text)
   {
      if (DatabaseContextInsert == null)
      {
          DatabaseContextInsert = DataContextHelper.GetDataContext();            
      }

      var log = new Log { Text = text };          

      lock (DatabaseContextInsert)
      {
        DatabaseContextInsert.GetTable<Log>().InsertOnSubmit(log);
        DatabaseContextInsert.SubmitChanges();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Would you like to show some code?

Comment: I think this will help you [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481956/linq-to-sql-datacontext-for-a-web-application][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481956/linq-to-sql-datacontext-for-a-web-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a static logger would be a very bad idea. In addition to synchronization issues, you would have problems with all the items being held in the data-context forever (a data-context likes to keep hold of objects it has seen).

You mention that you think that lots of data-contexts isn't good for optimisation, but the connection is presumably already pooling (it does that by default), so the data-context isn't actually very "heavy".

If the log entries do not need to be inserted synchronously, I would be tempted to do something like throwing new log items into a queue (synchronizing access), and having a worker thread that empties the queue every 10 seconds, essentially doing something like:

```
// adding an item
lock(queue) { queue.Enqueue(text); }


// worker code, every 10 seconds
List<string> items = new List<string>();
lock(queue) {
    while(queue.Count != 0) items.Add(items.Dequeue);
}
using(var ctx = CreateContext()) {
    foreach(var text in items) {
        ctx.Logs.InsertOnSubmit(new Log { Text = text });
    }
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Then only one thread is writing to the database, and you have far fewer transactions.

If this *isn't* an option, and you need to do it synchronously, then frankly I'd drop down a few levels to something like "dapper", i.e.

```
using(var conn = CreateOpenConnection()) {
    conn.Execute("insert [Log]([Text]) values(@text)", new {text});
}
```

which removes the need for a data-context *at all*, is much simpler, and removes the transaction from consideration.

Comment: It is critical that the log entries are saved - so a thread with a delay will not be a perfect solution (need to track why in example the application melts down, that might prevent the thread from finishing).
But the simple SQL add might be a good solution, there is no need to track the added objects since theire newer going to be changed. But is there a simple LINQ-to-SQL way to create this simple insert?  I have a lot more fields than "text", so using objects instead of a  SQL string for insert is preferable.